# Python: select a subsentence out of a text that contains a specific word

Tags: python

My dataset contains a column with a lot of text. Each row in that column contains multiple sentences.

I want to search for (sub)sentences in the text containing the word 'dentist' and delete all the other sentences. And then save the correct text.

When one row contains the text: **"My dentist is great. However the assistent is horrible. I just love the dentist."**
Result should be: **"My dentist is great. I just love the dentist."**

This is my script so far, df is my dataset:

```
sentence= df['columnwithtext']
for subsentence in sentence.split("."):
    if "dentist" in subsentence:
        print(subsentence)
```

However, when I run this script, I get nothing, not even an error...what is missing?

Then I tried this script:

```
df_dentist=df[df['columnwithtext'].str.contains("dentist")]
df_dentist
```

But then I get the whole sentence of a row where the word 'dentist' occurs, also sentences that I don't need.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show few lines of you df and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for (findall with join).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["My dentist is great. However the assistent is horrible. I just love the dentist.",
                   "No dentist is good. Every dentist is bad. This is not correct",
                   "Dentist or not. dentist is a dentist."], columns = ['dental'])

df.dental.str.findall(r'([^\.]+dentist[^\.]*\.)').apply(''.join)
```

which gives the following output:

```
0    My dentist is great. I just love the dentist.
1        No dentist is good. Every dentist is bad.
2                            dentist is a dentist.
Name: dental, dtype: object
```

Comment: If you need multiple words you can use the following: 

df.dental.str.findall(r'([^\.]+(?:dentist|assistant)[^\.]*\.)').apply(''.join)

Comment: Super, I found another way for that, but yours is easier!

Comment: Please accept the answer, if that solved your problem.